# Intersection of an arbitrary subgroup with one of finite index

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I want to show that if $G$ is a group and $[G:H]$ is finite, then so is $[K:H \cap K]$ for any $K < G$.

I think I can do this by showing that $k \in K \implies k(H \cap K) = (kH) \cap K$.  Is there a nicer way?

Comment: Do you have all three isomorphism theorems?  Also, what have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can show there is an injection from the set of left cosets of $K\cap H$ in $K$ to the set of left cosets of $H$ in $G$.

Answer (score 1):

If $H$ has finite index for in $G$ then there exists a normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ of finite index which is contained in $H$. To see this, consider the action of $G$ on $H$ by left multiplication. Then $N$ is the kernel of this action.

Then, it is sufficient to prove the result we are after for normal subgroups of finite index. The result then follows from the following (the second?) isomorphism theorem.
$$\frac{K}{N\cap K}\cong\frac{KN}{N}$$